# How to check if correct email address is entered?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$to =  "info@bodom.eu"; 
$subject =  "Form"; 
$name_field =  $_POST['name']; 
$email_field =  $_POST['email']; 
$message =  $_POST['message']; 

$body =  "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message"; 

echo "<div id='messageok'> Ok. <br /><span> Thank you. </span></div>"; 
mail($to, $subject, $body);
}  else { 
echo "<div id='messageok'> Error. </div>";
} 
?>
```

and I need to check if the fields in the form are filled and if e-mail address is correct. Yes, I found many tutorials, but I am not very good in PHP and this code works for me. Thank you.

Comment: What'a a "correct" email address? RFC822 compliant? One that actually exists?

Comment: You need to remove the real email address from your code.

Comment: The correct answer is: don't.  Either just assume they've given you a correct email address, or if you *absolutely must* check it, check it by sending an email to it with a verification link.  Proper email address verification is extremely tricky, and if you leave room for any false negatives ("what do you mean ``"bob+smith  27"@bob.museum`` is an invalid email address??  I use it every day!") then you're going to drive away users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to check valid email

http://www.google.com/search?q=valid+email+address+php+preg_match

this one for example

```
function checkEmail($email) {
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",
               $email)){
    list($username,$domain)=split('@',$email);
    if(!checkdnsrr($domain,'MX')) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```